# mysql select statement to pick only newly inserted records after cron job run

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want to select and use ONLY new records that have been inserted between a Cron job runs and the next run. In this sense I don't repeat any data or records that I worked on earlier.

From the select statement below, please someone direct me, thank you.

```
// select statement should pick fresh records only after the first cron
$sql = "SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); // fetch data
$name = $resultarr['name'];
$amount = $resultarr['amount'];
$transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];
$date = $resultarr['time_paid'];
```

This is important because the data will be used to send an SMS and I don't want to send an SMS twice to someone.

Kindly, anyone?

Comment: Set a flag in the db for SMS sent, so cron retrieves rows that have not been sent an SMS, send the SMS, then update the flag in the database

Comment: Kindly, how do I go about that. @Tristan

Comment: @BobMyles Have you got the Solution ?

Comment: just started implementation now. Will update

Comment: @BobMyles , that's cool go head.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get details of the newly inserted data, add a new column in your table like **add_date**. Check this add_date equals to current date. If yes you will get the details of every day's new date. You can use the below code.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$check_new_data = mysql_query("SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM 
customer WHERE add_date='$today'");

while($check = mysql_fetch_array($check_new_data))
{
            echo "What ever date you need";
}
```

Comment: @BobMyles I too use CRON job to check for new entry. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be certain that you only send the SMS once, then set a flag in the db table and update the flag once you have sent the SMS.

Add a field in the database table for the flag:

```
ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD `smsSent` BOOLEAN NOT NULL AFTER `time_paid`;
```

Select only where SMS not sent:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer WHERE smsSent = '0'";
```

You may want to add a limit to the SQL query to avoid any timeout or SMS sending limitations or throttling requirements.

Run the while loop on the records

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    // send the SMS
    /* add your sms sending code here */
    // update the database record so the sms is not sent again in future (assumes primary key is id)
    $sql = "UPDATE customer SET smsSent = '1' WHERE id = '{$resultarr['id']}'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

You could extend this functionality to log errors if the SMS fails to send.

Answer (score 0):

assumtion table_names and column names change it by yourself

```
    follow Vignesh Chinnaiyan steps and if you want dont sent message twice means create status table.

    id customer_id  insert_date           status 

     1    1        2016-06-13      sent
     2    2        2016-06-13      sent

     $check_new_data = mysql_query("SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM 
     customer WHERE add_date='$today' and  customer_id NOT IN (select customer_id from status_table where insert_date='$today') ");
```